# How to use OpenSSL with Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, linker, openssl

I am trying to port my console application written in `C` to Visual Studio 2010. On Linux/Mac, the application runs perfectly, including `OpenSSL` support.

Can anyone provide help using/linking the `OpenSSL` libs in a Visual Studio project?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you install Win32 OpenSSL?  If not, go here: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: What is the licence it carries ? I am not sure if it can be included in a commercial product... any ideas can help

Comment: Do you have the OpenSSL windows lib with you? What problem are you exactly facing when you try to link with OpenSSL Libs?

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to include openssl in Visual Studio Expres 2012 Windows 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156336/how-to-include-openssl-in-visual-studio-expres-2012-windows-7-x64).

Comment: This is NOT too broad. It has quite a specific solution.

Answer (score 39):

I know it's old! I faced the problem myself and here's the solution.

First of all, you should install (normal ordinary installation) openssl. (It's from [here](https://www.openssl.org/community/binaries.html)).

Now, after you create a project, I quote:

> Make sure the following settings are setup in the project property
> pages:
>
> [C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories] value:
> OpenSSL’s include directory in your machine (e.g C:\openssl\include)
>
> [Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories] value: OpenSSL’s
> lib directory in your machine (e.g C:\openssl\lib)
>
> [Linker -> Input
> -> Additional Dependencies] value: libeay32.lib

[Source](http://www.askyb.com/cpp/using-openssl-cryptography-blowfish-des-rc2-rc4/).

Comment: Hi joker can you please explain the install process. That link doesnt have any exe to run. I cloned from github, but am now stuck.

Comment: @Noitidart, what OS are you using?

Comment: Thanks very much @joker for your reply. I have been struggling really hard. I am on Win10, I created this topic explaining what I did and asking for help - http://stackoverflow.com/q/41357374/1828637

Comment: Just install one from here: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
I have used this method.

Comment: Thanks @Joker! I will try it out. Also I'm new to C++, I just want to make sure, when I `#include` these, then my users won't have to install OpenSSL too right? They can use it even if its not installed?

Comment: I'm not really about this part. I think (possibly) that if you compile the project as a release, this will omit the need at the user end to install the library. Meaning, if I am correct, when you compile the project, the user doesn't need to install the library. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Thanks joker for your thoughts I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 15):

Add OpenSSL-related header files, and below headers:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

Open below Link & download pre-compiled files.

http://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-openssl/

extract and keep folder in C drive 
use readme_precompile.txt for instructions.

Open Visual C++ project and followup procedure given in below to include and Linker options.

Make sure the following settings are setup in the project property pages:

- [C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories]

  - OpenSSL’s include directory in your machine (e.g C:\openssl\include) or  (e.g C:\openssl\include64)
- [Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories]

  - OpenSSL’s lib directory in your machine (e.g C:\openssl\lib) or (e.g C:\openssl\lib64)
- [Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies]

  - `ws2_32.lib`
  - `libsslMT.lib`
  - `Crypt32.lib`
  - `libcryptoMT.lib`

Comment: "http://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-openssl/" appears inaccessible now.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some resources: [Compiling and installing OpenSSL for Windows](http://www.askyb.com/windows/compiling-and-installing-openssl-for-32-bit-windows/), as well as [Using OpenSSL for Cryptography (Blowfish, DES, RC2, RC4)](http://www.askyb.com/cpp/using-openssl-cryptography-blowfish-des-rc2-rc4/)

I have tried them myself yet I am still getting errors. OpenSSL and Visual Studio are not my forte, but maybe you can figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is more than a year old, but I couldn't find the answer so I muscled my way through.  I got openssl-1.0.1e to compile using VS 11 as such:

I tried using the PERL that comes with git, didn't work, had to install [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/ActivePerl)

Taken from the [link](http://www.askyb.com/windows/compiling-and-installing-openssl-for-32-bit-windows/) provided by Nitesh:

```
perl Configure VC-WIN64A no-asm
```

Followed by:

```
ms\do_win64a
```

Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548138/how-to-compile-x64-code-with-visual-studio-in-command-line), I edited ms\ntdll.mak and changed CC to:

```
CC="c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe"
```

Then finally:

```
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
```

I didn't bother installing and just added the directory openssl-1.0.1e\out32dll to Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories and openssl-1.0.1e\inc32 to Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories, copied libeay32.dll to somewhere in my path, and called it good.  Seems to be working.

Comment: This is the "build openssl from source" approach, if all you want to do is compile against it, it's much easier to get the binaries.