# Cannot find libeay32.lib and ssleay32.lib files when setting up openssl on windows x64

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, openssl

So I am trying to use openssl inside Visual Studio for some encryption project.
These are the steps I did until now:

1. Download Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.1b from [here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).
2. Set `Additional Include Directories` to point to the oppenssl/include directory (from instalation)
3. Set `Additional Dependencies` inside Linker to: `libcrypto.lib`
4. Set `Additional Library Directories` inside Linker to point to the openssl/lib directory (from instalation)

Now when I build I still get lots of undefined references errors.

From what I read I still need to include the `libeay32.lib` and `ssleay32.lib`, but I didn't find them anywhere in my openssl instalation directory.

I followed this links for help:

[How to use OpenSSL with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383942/how-to-use-openssl-with-visual-studio)

[How to include openssl in Visual Studio Expres 2012 Windows 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156336/how-to-include-openssl-in-visual-studio-expres-2012-windows-7-x64)

Aparently my only issue now is that I am missing this files. Anyone know where can I find them ?

Comment: yes, forgot to mention, I've downlaoded the 43 MB version

Answer (score 24, accepted):

"How to" out of date.
Since version 1.1.0 OpenSSL have changed their library names from:
libeay32.dll -> libcrypto.dll
ssleay32.dll -> libssl.dll

https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/issues/1931

I see now:

[image]

- `MD`: Multi-threaded DLL
- `MDd`: Multi-threaded Debug DLL
- `MT`: Multi-threaded (static)
- `MTd` Multi-threaded (static) Debug

Comment: That's what I included for testing for Additional Dependencies and still errors :( I am using the .libs files

Comment: Do you know which one of those files to use for Win X64 ? I see there are 4 differents one: MD, MDd, MT, MTd

Comment: @Adrian, I've edited the answer to explain. Is this sufficient?

Comment: Thank you, I had thought that there is something wrong in openssl installation because libeay32.dll was missing. Turns out the name has changed