# Error installing Bitcoinlib | Python3, Windows10

Tags: python, bitcoinlib

Haven't seen this be posted anywhere yet, I installed OpenSSL for windows.
Getting the same error installing `Scrypt`

Python3, Windows 10. Tried using a different version of python but with no avail.

```
 Running setup.py install for scrypt ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Victor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-skwtkpny\\scrypt\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Victor\\AppData\\Local
\\Temp\\pip-install-skwtkpny\\scrypt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C
:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vzndvgwk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python39\Include\scrypt'
         cwd: C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-skwtkpny\scrypt\
    Complete output (50 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt
    copying scrypt\scrypt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt
    copying scrypt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    copying scrypt\tests\test_scrypt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    copying scrypt\tests\test_scrypt_c_module.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    copying scrypt\tests\test_scrypt_py2x.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    copying scrypt\tests\test_scrypt_py3x.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    copying scrypt\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    copying scrypt\tests\ciphertexts.csv -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    copying scrypt\tests\hashvectors.csv -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    running build_ext
    building '_scrypt' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\lib
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\lib\crypto
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\lib\scryptenc
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\lib\util
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\libcperciva
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\libcperciva\alg
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\libcperciva\crypto
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\libcperciva\util
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-windows-stubs
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.
1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Isc
rypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python39\include -Ic:\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Co
mmunity\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0
\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/
crypto/crypto_scrypt.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt.obj
    crypto_scrypt.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.
1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Isc
rypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python39\include -Ic:\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Co
mmunity\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0
\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/
crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix.obj
    crypto_scrypt_smix.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.
1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Isc
rypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python39\include -Ic:\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Co
mmunity\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0
\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/
crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix_sse2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix_sse2.obj
    crypto_scrypt_smix_sse2.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.
1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Isc
rypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python39\include -Ic:\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Co
mmunity\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0
\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/
scryptenc/scryptenc.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc.obj
    scryptenc.c
    scrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc.c(125): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'double', possible loss of data
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.
1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Isc
rypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python39\include -Ic:\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Co
mmunity\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0
\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/
scryptenc/scryptenc_cpuperf.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc_cpuperf.obj
    scryptenc_cpuperf.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.
1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Isc
rypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python39\include -Ic:\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Co
mmunity\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0
\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/
util/memlimit.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/util/memlimit.obj
    memlimit.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.
1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Isc
rypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python39\include -Ic:\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Co
mmunity\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0
\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/libc
perciva/alg/sha256.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg/sha256.obj
    sha256.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.
1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Isc
rypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python39\include -Ic:\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Co
mmunity\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0
\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/libc
perciva/crypto/crypto_aes.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto/crypto_aes.obj
    crypto_aes.c
    scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto/crypto_aes.c(6): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/aes.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Victor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-skwtkpny\\scrypt\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'
C:\\Users\\Victor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-skwtkpny\\scrypt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"
'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vzndvgwk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python39\Include\scrypt' Check the logs for full command
output.
```

Stackoverflow won't let me post cause it says most of my post is code but it's just the error log so I'm posting this so it'll let me post. I think I've giffen sufficient information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot open include file: 'openssl/aes.h': No such file or directory

You would need the OpenSSL development files to build that library. This answer seems related: [How to use OpenSSL with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383942/how-to-use-openssl-with-visual-studio)

Failing that, it looks like `scrypt` has wheels (precompiled binary packages) for Python 3.8 on Windows: https://pypi.org/project/scrypt/#files

So if it's possible for you to switch to Python 3.8, that would also likely solve your problem.