# how to reference ssleay32.dll in visual studio c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to c++. I have creating a previous copy of the exe application and using the ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll in visual studio 2017. I have added its path in the C++/General/Include directories and Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies and VC++/Include directories and added the dll in debug folder and current directory. but still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I am unable to include the <openssl/ssl.h> in the cpp file in the project

Any help to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use OpenSSL with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383942/how-to-use-openssl-with-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-160) for reference.

1. project->properties->configuration properties->C/C++->General->Addtional Include Directories->add the path of dll
2. project->properties->configuration properties->Linker->General->Addtional Library Directories->add the path of dll
3. project->properties->configuration properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

For the header file,  you could click `Project—>Configuration Properties—>C/C++—>General` and add the folder path where the .h file is located in the `Additional Include Directories`.