# How do I fix error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwInit

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, glfw, unresolved-external

I have the basic code from the vulkan tutorial. I'm not using Visual Studio and opted to just compile from the command line. `cl lib/*.lib main.cpp /I include`. I sort of assumed that the symbols would be resolved in the .*lib* files which seem to compile properly, but it doesn't link so what do I do?

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE
#include <glm/vec4.hpp>
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Vulkan window", nullptr, nullptr);

    uint32_t extensionCount = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);

    std::cout << extensionCount << " extensions supported\n";

    glm::mat4 matrix;
    glm::vec4 vec;
    auto test = matrix * vec;

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the full output of the compiler/linker

```
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29913.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
lib/glfw3.lib
lib/glfw3dll.lib
lib/glfw3_mt.lib
main.obj
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties@12 referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwInit referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwTerminate referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwWindowHint referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwCreateWindow referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwDestroyWindow referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwWindowShouldClose referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwPollEvents referenced in function _main
lib\glfw3.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
lib\glfw3dll.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
lib\glfw3_mt.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
```

Comment: According to the message, you look like trying to link libraries for x64 with application code for x86. You should match the kind of the target.

Comment: ***lib\glfw3.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'*** Tells you that you are mixing 64 bit and 32 bit.

Comment: Related if not a duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548138/how-to-compile-x64-code-with-visual-studio-in-command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548138/how-to-compile-x64-code-with-visual-studio-in-command-line)

Comment: It really would be a lot easier to use Visual Studio. You would have less to assume.

Comment: @john Seconded, and as a bonus you get a first-class debugger thrown in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I had to install the windows 10 SDK
Then I had to change my vcvarsall in path to the VS2022 one
Then I had to run the `vcvarsall x64`
Then I had to remove the `glfw3.lib` in favor of the `glfw3_mt.lib`
Then I had to add the `vulkan-1.lib` to my `lib/` directory
And finally it compiled and showed a window

Comment: And how do you plan to debug it?

Comment: @PaulSanders My strategy is to not write code with bugs

Comment: Well good luck with that.  Wish I could do it.